# update Ui with TimeTask in android

Tags: android

I am running a countdown timer in android and i want to show this countdown to the user in an Activity with a TextView. How can i do this? Has any one done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Methods,

First Method involves, Using a `Handler`. [See my Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic/3734070#3734070) Its not a countdown, but it should show you how to use a `Handler`.

Second Method involves, Using `runOnUIThread()`, by running a `Runnable` with the implementation of your countdown.