# Android: Timer to show in he UI

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, recorder

I've written a Audio Recorder for my application. Now I want to show a timer in the application that ticks as long as user does the recording.

How can I acheive this?? Any tutorials or links please. I've tried to do it in thread and I couldn't think of a logic.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard about the **chronometer** in android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

[Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ChronometerDemo.html)

Answer (score 3):

check this:

[stop watch logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic)

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

you can this as a timer:

```
new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //Do your task.......
            }
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //update your timer value here and show it......
            }
}.start();
```