# Stream output of variable

Tags: android, time, stream, boolean

I have this method:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (test != true) {
                test = true;
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH 'hours', mm 'mins,' ss 'seconds'");
                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+0"));  
                tv.setText(df.format(new Date(end)));
            } else {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH 'hours', mm 'mins,' ss 'seconds'");
                end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+0"));  
                tv.setText(df.format(new Date(end)));

            }
```

I would like to have the "tv" variable keep outputting the time value, without stop after the "else" statement - so I will always see the current value of the time.

I have try to make a loop through a boolean, but without success.

Comment: Are you making some kind of stopwatch?

Comment: what is the problem when you tried to loop?

Comment: Yes I am trying to make kind of stopwatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highgly recommend using a `Handler` for the job.

Having already answered this question before, you may find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic/3734070#3734070). It's a complete program.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot loop on the main (UI) thread—that will lock up the app. You will need to create a worker thread to do the timing. It will periodically post a runnable to the UI thread update `tv`.

There are many ways to do this in Android. Here's some sample code for a simple, home-grown approach:

```
private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH 'hours', mm 'mins,' ss 'seconds'");
        end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+0"));  
        tv.setText(df.format(new Date(end)));
    }
}

private class TimerThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                sleep(1000L);
                runOnUiThread(updater);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create and start a `TimerThread` in `onResume()` and interrupt it in `onPause()` (so it will exit).

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the time make use the of [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)