# Android StopWatch - Time is increasing very fast

Tags: android, stopwatch

I'm making a stopwatch application for android. I have one button for start and stop. My problem is that the time is increasing very fast. Where i'm getting wrong. Bellow is the code:

```
        final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            if (startIsPressed) {
                time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - initStart + startPointTime;
                startPointTime = time;
            } else {
                time = startPointTime;
            }

            hh = time / 3600000;
            hours.setText("" + formatter.format(hh));
            time = time - hh * 3600000;

            mm = time / 60000;
            minutes.setText("" + formatter.format(mm));
            time = time - mm * 60000;

            ss = time / 1000;
            seconds.setText("" + formatter.format(ss));
            time = time - ss * 1000;

            millis.setText("" + formatter.format(time / 10));

            handler.postDelayed(this, 30);
        }
    };
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!startIsPressed) {
                startIsPressed = true;
                startBtn.setText(R.string.stop);
                initStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                handler.post(updater);
            } else {
                startIsPressed = false;
                startBtn.setText(R.string.start);
                handler.post(updater);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: see this post maybe helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic

Comment: thanks for replay, but still my problem is how to start counting the time where has stopped. The example shown in the link, only stops the timer and starts from beginning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as doc say [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses.Update your timer every 1 second as:
use

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 100); //100 milliseconds refresh rate
```

instead of

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 30); //30 milliseconds refresh rate
```

and see stopwatch logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic)