# Android Timer And UI Thread

Tags: android, timer, inflate

I inflate a TableRow like this:

```
final TableRow tr1 = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.attrib_row_survey, null);
tr1.setOnTouchListener(this);
tl1.addView(tr1);
```

This is how I do my counter:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                     ((TextView)tr1.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                 }

                 public void onFinish() {
                     ((TextView)tr1.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("DONE");
                 }
              }.start();
```

The problem is, when I run this timer and show it in the row, the UI is very slow and the timer lags.  When I do a view.setBackGroundColor(Color.BLACK) in the onTouchListener() and I click on it, it lags.

Comment: One improvement is to save a reference to the `textView2` rather than calling `findViewById()` repeatedly. However the CountDownTimer is unlikely to create any noticeable lag, what else are you doing?

Comment: May i interest you in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected static void startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true; 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            elapsedTime += 1; //increase every sec
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

   public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           StopWatch.time.setText(formatIntoHHMMSS(elapsedTime)); //this is the textview
     }
    }
```

Comment: So, how do I stop the countdown timer from doing onTick if the TableRow onTouchListener is activated? It lags everytime I touch the TableRow.