# How to record audio file using timer

Tags: android, audio-recording, countdowntimer

Hi i am new for android and in my app i have to record audio using timer as like my below image, Using my below i can able record audio but how can do this scenario with help of timer please help me some

### My code:-

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.record_button:
             startRecording()
                break;

            case R.id.stop_button:
                break;

        }
    }


    private void startRecording() {

        try {

            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {

        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just start a timer in `startRecording` and stop it in `stopRecording`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734070/2324204

Comment: @AbhiRam Then you should tell people what _is_ suitable to your app... "_record audio using timer_" doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: what is wrong in this i want to record audio with timer

Comment: what is meaning less here?

Comment: You presumably know what you want, but you're not explaining it well. The phrase "record audio with a timer" doesn't make much sense because you record audio with a `MediaRecorder`... do you mean you want to display a timer _while_ you are recording audio? ... do you mean you want to record audio for a fixed time and stop when a timer reaches zero? ... or do you mean something else entirely that I've not thought of.  Unless you can get across what it is you're trying to do, people aren't going to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer) which already exists in Android.

Note: Chronometer is a widget that extends TextView so replace your current TextView with the Chronometer.

Example with your code would be:

```
//....
    Chronometer simpleChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer);

//...



private void startRecording() {

    try {

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        simpleChronometer.start(); // start a chronometer
        //simpleChronometer.setFormat("Time Running - %s"); // set the format  for a chronometer

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {

    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
    simpleChronometer.stop();
}
```

In case you want to do things manually you can use the [Stopwatch](https://github.com/cgoldberg/netplot/blob/0cdac581460f70a3d39929ffb5a2635a9eb16320/src/Stopwatch.java) class.